# PHP form post dont send message

Tags: php, forms, post

In this page, the PHP doesn't seems to work.
http://www.lesconstructionsvignoul.com/contact-us.html

I tried to see if the php file was missing but it's there and the path is good.

Someone can help me with this?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="form_process/contact.php" method="post">
```

Here's the contact.php code:

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post){
$to = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"; // Your e-mail here
$name = stripslashes($_POST['inputName']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = stripslashes($_POST['inputSubject']);
$message = stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);
$sendToYourself = stripslashes($_POST['sendToYourself']);

$headers = (!empty($sendToYourself)) ? 'Reply-To: '.$email . "\r\n" . " ";
$headers .= "From: ".$name."\r\n" ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

$mail = mail($to, $headers, $subject, $message);

if($mail){
    echo 'OK!';
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Could you add `contact.php` code to your question?

Comment: Seeing that you have beautiful design and are using jQuery anyways, why don't you try AJAX?

Comment: try adding `else` statements too.

Comment: I used a template thaht came with contact forms. I'm good at HTML/CSS and a little bit of JS but not a JS guru :-P

Comment: Doesn't seem to work is the worst error message EVER!  Is it a 404, a PHP parse error.. There are likely logs to review somewhere. Anyway, if this form file is in the same directory as the form process directory, try `action="./form_process/...`

Comment: Your design is very good :) keep going. (I don't care templates nice desgin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you wrote your parameters wrong. You wrote:

```
mail($to, $headers, $subject, $message);
```

It should be:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, headers);
```

**Why?**

Because `$headers` are additional(optional).[php.net](http://php.net/manual/sr/function.mail.php). You first need to write the required paramterers.

> Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

PHP `mail` [SYNTAX](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

so should your code is

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, headers);
```